# List View Problem

Tags: android, listview, items

i have a problem in a list view.. i want to put different fields in the same listview is this possible?

like this?

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(.this);
        db.open();
        List<String> ct = new ArrayList<String>();      
        ct = db.getAllAccounts();   
        List<String> sd = new ArrayList<String>();      
        sd = db.getAllAmount();         
        Account = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_addAccount);
        Account.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_contas_layout,R.id.text1,R.id.text2, ct,sd));
```

theres something like this to use?
sorry about my english;)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Take a look at [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). I'm not sure what database you're using, but using the `Cursor` class is pretty normal for this sort of thing. Otherwise you're going to have to create your own custom adapter.

Comment: Can you explain better? do you have some example? my problem is in this line Account.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_contas_layout,R.id.text1,R.id.text2, ct,sd)); this is not possible to do this way, but i wan't to now if exists something like this.. to put two diferent values in a listview

Comment: Using the SimpleCursorAdapter is a fairly different approach and I really can't help you much there without knowing more about what your DB looks like. I'll post a different answer that you can try that's a little closer to what you currently have.

Comment: Actually, first to clarify: do you want all the accounts and amounts each as list items? Or do you want account/amount pairs with a list item containing one TextView for the account and one TextView for the amount?

Comment: i want account/amount with a listview containing the account and the other the amount..